# How to legalize a hack which assumes adjacent storage of a derived class variable?

Tags: c++

While analyzing a 3rd party code, I came across a hack, which assumes that the variable in a base class is stored adjacently to another variable of a class that is derived from it.  The derived class adds a checksum variable and a function, that calculates a hash of the data from the Base Class concatenated with the checksum in the Derived Class.

This hack works, but it seems that the assumption it makes, cannot be relied upon.
The abridged code illustrating this, is listed below ( see the comment: "UGLY HACK!" ) :

```
template<unsigned int BYTES>
class BaseClass {
protected:
        unsigned char xdata[BYTES];

public:
        BaseClass() { memset(&xdata[0], 0, sizeof(xdata));  };
        void FooFn() {};
        unsigned char* BigFn() {};
};


template<unsigned int BYTES>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<BYTES> {
protected:
    __int64 checksum;

    __int64 CalcChecksum(unsigned char* pBegin, unsigned char* pEnd);

public:
    DerivedClass();

    void HashOfDataAndChecksum(unsigned __int64* outputhash);
};    
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

template<unsigned int BYTES>
__int64 DerivedClass<BYTES>::CalcChecksum(unsigned char* pBegin, unsigned char* pEnd) {
    __int64 sum = 0;

    while (pBegin++ < pEnd)
        sum += *pBegin;

    return ~sum;
}

template<unsigned int BYTES>
DerivedClass<BYTES>::DerivedClass() {
    checksum = CalcChecksum(&BaseClass<BYTES>::xdata[0], &BaseClass<BYTES>::xdata[sizeof(BaseClass<BYTES>::xdata)]);
}

template<unsigned int BYTES>
void DerivedClass<BYTES>::HashOfDataAndChecksum(unsigned __int64* outputhash) {
    int i;
    unsigned char* pBegin = &BaseClass<BYTES>::xdata[0];
    unsigned char* pEnd = (unsigned char*)(&checksum) + sizeof(checksum);  //UGLY HACK!  Works only if the checksum immediately follows xdata[] in memory.
    unsigned char* x = pBegin;

    while (x < pBegin + ( (pEnd-pBegin) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC0) )
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        {
            XCOMPRESS(x[0], x[8], x[16], x[24], x[32], x[40], x[48], x[56]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[24], x[16], x[8], x[0], x[56], x[48], x[40], x[32]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[32], x[48], x[0], x[16], x[24], x[40], x[56], x[8]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[8], x[32], x[56], x[48], x[40], x[0], x[24], x[16]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[48], x[40], x[56], x[0], x[32], x[24], x[16], x[8]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[16], x[40], x[8], x[48], x[24], x[56], x[0], x[16]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[56], x[48], x[24], x[16], x[8], x[0], x[32], x[40]);
            XCOMPRESS(x[8], x[24], x[40], x[56], x[0], x[16], x[32], x[48]);
            CROSS_NORMALIZE(&x[0]);
        }
        x += 64;
    }

    for (i=0; i < ((pEnd-pBegin) & (size_t)0x3f); i++ )
    {
        //A lot more hashing code
    }

};


int main()
{
    BaseClass<1048576> b;
    assert(sizeof(b) == 1048576);  //This must be true because the code that uses the BaseClass relies on sizeof() this way a lot.

    DerivedClass<1048576> d;
    assert( sizeof(d) == 1048576 + sizeof(__int64) ); //This must be true because the code that uses the DerivedClass relies on sizeof() to be the sum of the BaseClass and DerivedClass storages.

    unsigned __int64 h[8];
    d.FooFn();  //This function operates only on the xdata of the BaseClass
    d.HashOfDataAndChecksum(&h[0]);  //This function calculates a hash of the xdata in the BaseClass concatenated with the checksum in the DerivedClass
}
```

How to legalize this hack without resorting to copying the xdata and checksum to a 3rd variable adjacently ?   ...and without modifying the hashing algorithm or the size of the base class?

Comment: [`std::is_standard_layout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) must be true, and then you could use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) otherwise this is UB as far as I know.

Comment: Tagging the class with __attribute__((packed)) might be a way to ensure the data really is layed out contiguously.

Comment: You can't legalize your hack.  The only thing we know about a standard layout class is the first member shares the same address as the class. after that there could be padding.  Your asserts at least will stop it from compiling if your assumptions break.

Comment: @Jeremy  Do you think __attribute__((packed)) or #pragma pack(1) have any influence on the memory layout of derived class member variables ?

Comment: @KarolaN I would expect them to (assuming you apply the tags to both the base and derived classes), although I admit I've never tried it myself so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Mgetz  The user "etarion" wrote, that this is not a "standard layout" because it contains data members in different classes of the inheritance hierarchy and the "offsetof" might work only with C++17 compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `offsetof` and assert that the offset of `checksum` is in the expected place. Your code will probably work as-is anywhere, but if someone mucks up the base class, your code may no longer work. Safest is the hard way.

Comment: offsetof is only guaranteed to work for standard layout types, this is not a standard layout type (it has data members in different classes of the inheritance hierarchy). Before C++17, using offsetof on a non-standard-layout class is undefined (and OP is unlikely to use a C++17 compiler already), from C++17 it's an optional feature (does not need to be implemented).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make this legal is to change the base class to `xdata[BYTES + sizeof(std::int64_t)]`. This way, you don't need to copy both `xdata` and `checksum` to a third variable; instead you just copy `checksum` to the reserved space at the end of `xdata`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first assert() will fail after such modification

Comment: That seems like an incorrect assumption to start with, regardless of my proposed modification. So it's probably worth fixing that as well.

Comment: From the beginning, I was clear in my question, that this type of solution is unacceptable.  I specifically wrote "...without resorting to copying the xdata and checksum to a 3rd variable adjacently ".

Comment: @KarolaN: Well, the whole point of this solution is to copy only the checksum,not `xdata`. Copying an 8 byte value with locality of reference is practically free.

Comment: Yes, copying 8 bytes of checksum has minimum performance penalty, but increasing the size of xdata[] changes the result of sizeof(xdata) and the size of entire class instance, that contains it.  This breaks the code code that uses this base class all over the place.  I did not exclude changing these sizes, but I am going to do it now.